# Network lost on screen lock unlock

Tags: ios, iphone, nsurlconnection

Encountered a very weird problem, using simple `AFNetworking` downloading operation, even tried with simple `NSURLConnection` operation, connection fails if you keep your app running, and lock screen and then unlock. Works absolutely fine in `background` though.

Any one encountered similar problem with `NSURLConnection` want to share some solution?

Thanks.

Comment: It only fail once the user *unlock* the screen ?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like an iOS bug. Weird, but lock screen action affects `NSURLSession` somehow, so that it stops working and returns `NSURLErrorNetworkConnectionLost`. So in my app I gave up using shared session. I either use a new session object for every request or (if I need to maintain one session constantly) recreate it every time the screen gets unlocked. And it works. For users of `AFNetworking` or any other third party library working on top of `NSURLSession` the situation is harder, of course. You'll need to correct the code of the library, which is definitely not a good thing, but I think there's no other choice

Answer (score 0):

Very helpful [Andrey Chernukha](https://stackoverflow.com/users/994107/andrey-chernukha),
In my case, figured out that you don't necessary need to recreate new session every time.
I ended up using array to save running NSURLSessionDataTasks and after phone is unlocked resume them.

Steps:

1. I created array **NSMutableArray  *dataTasksToResume**
2. In **- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application** I saved all tasks to **dataTasksToResume** array
3. Cancel all running **NSURLSessionDataTasks**
4. In **- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application** get all tasks from array and resuming them (re-creating them)
5. Enjoy!

Hope it helps.